# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_profile.name

Tags: python, django, django-models, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot which is a database. If '@usename == None' it returns django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_profile.name What should I do ?

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    external_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='User ID',
        unique=True,
    )
    name = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='User name',
        default='None'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f' ID: {self.external_id} | Username: {self.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'


class Message(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        to='main.Profile',
        verbose_name='Profile',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Text',
    )
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'external_id',
            'name',
        )
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the answer above, this problem is almost always related to migration stuff, but in case it don't, I guess that in the `name` field of your `Profile` model, if you don't specify the constraint `null=True`, by default it would be `False` so it is saying that you are obliged to give a value (!= to an empty string), so:

if you are doing something like this:

```
def home_view(request):
    context ={}
  
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()

    context['form']= form

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

When the the form class receives the `request` if the `name` input has no data in it, it would look like `{"name" : ""}`, and becouse the request object have the name key first it not going to use the `default='None'` and then is going to pass it to the `create` method in the form, and based on the constraint defined for that particular field, the `db transaction` would rise the `django.db.utils.IntegrityError` becouse at DB level, that field is not allowed to be `NULL`

Django docs:

"Field.null : If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False."

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the last few migrations, you can do all except the `0001_initial.py`. Then just go and do `python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name` and then `python manage.py migrate` and it should be solved